# Debugging Windows service failure before main() (error 1053 when run by LocalSystem user)

Tags: c++, windows

I have a Windows service that works perfectly when run via a user account, but fails with error 1053 when run by the Local System account. Unfortunately, whatever is going wrong happens before my main() function is called, which means I can't even insert logging calls to track down where things go wrong.

How can I debug Windows service startup failures when it's happening in pre-main() code?

Any ideas why it might fail specifically when it's run by the Local System user?

NOTE: Not sure if it's relevant, but I'm compiling with GCC, and the code depends on Cygwin.

Comment: Error suggests that the service takes 'too long' to respond. You might want to review the event logs.

Comment: There's nothing in the event logs. As I said, execution *never* reaches main(), i.e., my code is never run, and the compiler generated startup code isn't going to call the Windows event logger.

Comment: Change any global variables that do _"anything interesting"_ so that you can lazy initialise them in main.  Anything interesting is stuff like Access the Registry, Console, Anything that needs Security Permissions, Desktop access, User Directories etc

Comment: I forgot about global initialization. Will have to go through the code...

Comment: I would try creating a class object in global scope, and put a sleep in its constructor. If the crash happens after that object is constructed, then you have a (short) window of opportunity to attach your debugger to the service process while it is sleeping.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried doing that, but it didn't change the short time that it runs. So, whatever is killing it executes before the global's initialization.

Answer (score 0):

This won't be complete answer because without actually having event log it would not be possible.

- Since this happens pre-main this would be related to what your user account can do and what local system cannot.
- In service property panel, for Local System account you have "Allow Service To interact with desktop". Many times this can be the reason.
- The other of course is, your service is loading some libraries which are off limits to it - because of network\group security (local system cannot access network so far as I know).

You will need to eliminate one piece at time to see what happens. Or other way round - make service empty remove all dependencies and play 20 questions.

Comment: Thanks. The application event log is empty. I've already enabled/disabled the "Allow Service To interact with desktop" checkbox, so it's definitely not that.

Comment: As far as external libraries are concerned, why would any DLL be off-limits to the Local System user but accessible to regular users? And is there any way to find out which ones without having to remove/disable code to eliminate dependencies?

Comment: As why they are off limits - not sure. May be they access network. May be they try to access some location on local computer which requires administrative access. You can try to use two utilities: 1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer 2. https://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: Thanks. Process Explorer only shows ntdll.dll and the service itself in the DLLs list before failing. I'm not sure what to make of that. Dependency Walker doesn't work for me (just hangs).

Comment: Okay, if you have not gone through differences please do: https://mohamedradwan.com/2013/09/29/local-system-vs-network-service-vs-local-service-and-tfs-service-accounts/
But short of making service empty and staring all over, I suspect your best bet is service account (assuming you are in domain environment): https://sourcedaddy.com/windows-7/managing-service-accounts.html

Comment: I have now: created a minimal service that does nothing, switched to mingw to eliminate any Cygwin dependency, and statically linked the stdlibs. The last remaining DLLs being loaded are: ADVAPI32.dll, KERNEL32.dll, msvcrt.dll

It *still* fails before main(). The service code is based on Microsoft's own service example. I'm starting to suspect that the problem lies with the startup code generated by GCC.

Comment: Correction. The stripped down service code is working. I didn't pay enough attention to the error code...

Comment: I've now stripped down the actual service so that it only needs the exact same set of DLLs as the minimal test service, and it's still failing before main. So, it's not a DLL per-se.

Running as the LocalService user doesn't help.

Comment: Okay, could you update your question with stripped down version, one that is failing, of your **actual service** along with make files you are using? Mention compiler and version, windows you are using, whether you are in domain environment (just yes or no)

Comment: I've managed to trace it to some residual GUI code. This was masked earlier because, for some as yet unknown reason, I can't start the service as "Local System" or "Local User" from the build directory. I have to move it out first.

Comment: @HansdeRuiter This is probably a permissions issue "Local System" and "Local User" have very restricted rights on the file system.  Try giving them read and execute permissions on the build directory.

Comment: Yes Richard, the build folder's permissions were messed up. It worked after I fixed them.